# How to pin Spring Tool Suite to Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: taskbar, spring-tool-suite

When Spring Tool Suite is started, right-clicking on the icon in the task bar doesn't show the pin-to-taskbar option (only new task..., activate task... and close window are available). No option for pinning STS to the taskbar.

Is there any way to pin STS to the taskbar?

Comment: And how does this question not fit into "software tools commonly used by programmers" as defined by the community.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this issue with the x64 version of STS 3.2.0-RELEASE on Windows 7. The following worked for me which is also documented [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314805):

- Check your `eclipse.ini`  and make sure that the VM path points to the bin directory of your JDK or JRE *and not to javaw.exe*. For me the argument is `D:/Development/Languages/Java/Development Kit/bin/`
- Unpin Eclipse from the taskbar or delete the shortcut
- Run `eclipse.exe` from Windows Explorer and choose your workspace
- Pin Eclipse to the taskbar after the splash screen has loaded and when the main window is shown

Comment: This worked for me.  Edit STS.ini, remove the "javaw.exe" from the path on the 2nd line, save, and restart STS.  After the main window is loaded, you can then right-click the icon and pin to task bar.

Comment: I was using STS 3.6.4 (Keplar) and when I pinned it to the toolbar and opened an instance of it, it would still make a new ("active") button on the toolbar but when I upgraded to STS 3.7.4 (Mars) I noticed that when I pinned and opened, it actually stayed as 1 button (party)

Answer (score -1):

`click on start->all programs->Spring Source` And then `right click on STS release` , you will see `Pin to taskbar`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, because this will only pin the launcher - Once Spring Tool Suite is started, it will add a second icon to the task bar, just as Eclipse does, but with Eclipse it's possible to choose pin-to-taskbar once Eclipse has started. STS doesn't show this option